# Why g element is not starting from the corner of the svg when I have not given any translation for g element

Tags: html, d3.js, svg

I have drawn border around my svg element and then inside that svg element is g element. I am not sure why g element is NOT starting from the extreme left corner of the svg ? IMHO, the g must be starting from 0,0 of the svg element but don't know why it is displaced.

Similarly if i forcefully set g to width/2 and height/2, its starting point does not go to center of the svg but somewhere a head of it.

Looking forward thanks.

[image]

Similarly see the next figure, g is at (350, 250) after translation but this does not look at the center of the svg. Note 350 and 250 are the half of the svg which is(700 and 500).

[image]

Comment: Please add markup as text in the question and not as images.

Comment: You will need to add to the g a transparent rect starting from the extreme left corner of the svg. Otherwise the group starts where the leftmost element in the group starts. In javascript you can use `getBBox()` to get the position and the size of the group.

Comment: A group is merely a container for the elements inside, it does not have dimensions on its own nor is there a way to explicitly position the `g` element. The only way to manipulate the group's coordinate system is by applying a `transform` on it. Related: [*How does one get the height/width of an SVG group element?*](/questions/7620509).

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you so very much. It make sense and I have changed the code and it seems to be behaving as expected. Thanks again.

Comment: @altocumuls. Thank you. You are right.

Comment: @RobertLongson. Thanks. I'll be careful next time.